# Spring Data REST Controllers vs Custom Controllers

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have a 2 domain classes one with reference to another like this:

```
@Document
public class Dummy {

   @Id
   private UUID id;

   private String name;

   @Reference
   private DummyAttribute dummyAttribute;

   // getters and setters omitted.

}

@Document
public class DummyAttribute {

   @Id
   private UUID id;

   private String name;

   // getters and setters omitted.

}
```

I also have 2 repositories corresponding to Dummy and DummyAttribute.

```
public interface DummyRepository extends CrudRepository<Dummy, UUID> {

}

public interface DummyAttributeRepository extends 
CrudRepository<DummyAttribute, UUID> {

}
```

I want to create a `Dummy` with a `DummyAttribute`. So, I create a dummyAttribute by posting to `/dummyattributes`. I get the response body with a self link to dummyAttribute back. This self link that I get back is used during the creation of Dummy. My JSON payload to the `/dummies` looks like :

```
{
   "name" : "dummy",
   "dummyAttribute" : <self link of dummyAttribute generated during POST>
}
```

When I do a `GET` on the association URL generated after `POST`, I correctly get 
the dummyAttribute that was used. So far works well in Spring Data REST.

I want to do the same using my custom controllers. So, I created controllers
for both Dummy and DummyAttribute.

```
 @RestController
 public class DummyController  {

   @Autowired
   private DummyRepository dummyRepository;

   @Autowired
   private DummyResourceProcessor processor;

   @RequestMapping(value = "/dummies", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public HttpEntity<Resource<Dummy>> createTenant(@RequestBody Dummy dummy)
    {

       Dummy save = dummyRepository.save(dummy);
       Resource<Dummy> dummyr = new Resource<Dummy>(save);
       return new ResponseEntity<Resource<Dummy>>(processor.process(dummyr),
        HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/dummies/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public HttpEntity<Resource<Dummy>> getDummy(@PathVariable("id") Dummy
     dummy) {

      Resource<Dummy> dummyr = new Resource<Dummy>(dummy);
      return new ResponseEntity<Resource<Dummy>>(processor.process(dummyr),
      HttpStatus.OK);
   }


  @RestController
  public class DummyAttributeController  {

     @Autowired
     private DummyRepository dummyRepository;

     @Autowired
     private DummyAttributeRepository dummyAttributeRepository;

     @Autowired
     private DummyAttributeResourceProcessor processor;

     @RequestMapping(value = "/dummyAttributes", method = 
       RequestMethod.POST)
    public HttpEntity<Resource<DummyAttribute>> createDummyAttribute(
      @RequestBody DummyAttribute dummyAttribute) {
     DummyAttribute save = dummyAttributeRepository.save(dummyAttribute);
     Resource<DummyAttribute> dummyr = new Resource<DummyAttribute>(save);
      return new ResponseEntity<Resource<DummyAttribute>>
             (processor.process(dummyr),createHeaders(request,save.getId()),
         HttpStatus.CREATED);
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/dummyAttributes/{id}", method = 
     RequestMethod.GET)
   public HttpEntity<Resource<DummyAttribute>> getDummyAttribute(
     @PathVariable("id") DummyAttribute dummyAttribute) {

    Resource<DummyAttribute> dummyr = new Resource<DummyAttribute>
      (dummyAttribute);
    return new ResponseEntity<Resource<DummyAttribute>>  
      (processor.process(dummyr), HttpStatus.OK);
  }
```

I followed the same sequence of step as above. I did a POST to`dummyAttribute`.
Using this self link , I tried to create a `dummy`.

This time things are not so smooth. I get this exception back.

```
Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, 
class com.sudo.DummyAttribute] from String value   
('http://localhost:8080/dummyAttributes/3fa67f88-f3f9-4efa-a502-  
    bbeffd3f6025'); no single-String constructor/factory method at 
[Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@224c018a; line: 2, column: 19] 
(through reference chain: com.sudo.Dummy["dummyAttribute"])
```

When I create a constructor inside DummyAttribute, and I parse the id from the url and assign it to the id.

```
public DummyAttribute(String url) {

   String attrId = // parse the URL to get the id;

   this.id = attrId;
}
```

Now things are work as expected.The `dummyAttribute` is assigned to `dummy`.

What I would like to know is why are things different when I write my custom-controller ? What am I missing ? How is it that when I use Spring Data REST, the reference URL to the `dummyAttribute` was automatically resolved to the  corresponding dummyAttribute object and in the custom controller, I had to parse it manually and assign the id value explicitly to `domainAttribute id`?

Also, in the constructor I believe, the `dummyAttribute` is not resolved by finding it from repository by doing a findOne but a new `dummyAttribute` is being created. Is this correct?

How do I make my `POST`s to my custom controller work exactly like how it works in Spring Data REST ? Do I need a custom serializer/deserializer for this ? Do I need to register some components manually and invoked it ?

I found that when I have customer controllers and @EnableWebMvc is used, the associated resource does not get resolved. That results in the error above. If no @EnableWebMvc is present, then the associated resource gets resolved properly. Not sure how @EnableWebMvc gets in between....

The spring versions that I use are : spring-boot-starter-1.2.5, spring-boot-starter-data-rest-1.2.5, spring-data-commons-1.9.3. spring-hateoas-0.16.0, spring-data-rest-core-2.2.3, spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.2.3.

Comment: What Spring Data module versions are you using? Why has `DummyAttributes` a repository in the first place? Looks like it's not really an aggregate root.

Comment: Thanks for replying @OliverGierke. I have edited the original question with Spring versions and something that I found out.